# awakeFromNib is not getting called in Custom cell class due to which IBOutlets are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to iOS programming.I have created a customcell class and awakefromnib method is not getting called because of this the IBOutlets are comings as nil!
It is driving me crazy! Please help!
I am using storyboards not xibs.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/12629565/5362916

Comment: Using nib or storyboard?

Comment: try using `initWithCoder:`

Comment: Are you using initWithStyle: method? Then it won't work obviously. Please post your code for more help.

Comment: @SunilChauhan initWithStyle: in CellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @SunilChauhan   If I dont use initWithStyle: method in cellForRowAtIndexPath method then the cell is nil

Comment: if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kBMCustomGroupEmployeeCell];
    }

Comment: @SunilChauhan I removed initWithStyle method still not working

Comment: Just refer to some demos of UITableView. One can be:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: Can you paste the piece of code which you are using to initialize cell..

Answer (score 32):

I recently ran into this issue and it was due to incorrectly registering the cell. To have the `UITableViewCell` loaded from a nib you need to register like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // .....

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "YourCellNibName", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was registering the class instead of the nib, and that failed to load the nib entirely.

Answer (score 11):

I also ran into this issue and the problem was I was calling:

```
self.collectionView.register(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
```

even though I had actually added the collection view cell in the storyboard. If that's the case then registering the class is unnecessary and causes all your IBOutlets to be nil when the cell is dequeued

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the appropriate module (and not none) for the Custom Class of UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cell to be instantiated from a xib then you have the wrong implementation in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

You need to do a few things:

#### First:

Ensure that the `Identifier` of the cell is set to a nice unique value in the xib. (n.b. cell is not a nice unique name it's just for this example)

[image]

#### Second:

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method ensure that you create a cell using this reuse identifier

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  // configure cell

  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today simply because I forgot to set my custom class on the .xib's UIColletionViewCell:

[image]