# UICollectionViewCell awakeFromNib never called even though registerNib is called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

The code below attempts to create a `UICollectionView` within a custom view. Since the `UICollectionView` is not created in Storyboard, it means creating the custom `UICollectionViewCells` in a XIB.

However, the `awakeFromNib` function is never called for the custom `UICollectionViewCell`, which causes issues in rendering the `UICollectionView`.

How to fix this?

CustomView.swift:

```
class CustomView : UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private func doInit() {
        if let nibsView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomCellView", owner: self, options: nil) as? [UIView] {
            let nibRoot = nibsView[0]
            self.addSubview(nibRoot)
            nibRoot.frame = self.bounds

            // Register UICollectionViewCell NIB
            collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: CustomCellNib, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomCellID)
        }
    }
}
```

CustomCell.swift:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        doInit(frame)
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out my answer on this similar question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69439397/6923171

Answer (score 0):

change you line of code to be

```swift
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: CustomCellNib, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomCellID)
```